# Does "hopping" on one leg when running or walking fast indicate a medical problem?

Tags: dogs

I have a 9lb toy poodle and he is just the cutest. He loves walks, but when I take him he appears to almost skip a step and "hop" on one hind leg. I wonder if this has any negative effects on him or if anyone else has this issue with their dog, maybe it is a cramp? I hope this isn't something that is hurting him, it doesn't seem to though since he has no reaction when he does it. I would say he does this on 95% of our walks.

Comment: Our late terrier mutt used to do that. He did have a leg injury from when he was a pup, so its worth checking with your vet. He was fairly mobile till the last 6 months of his 15 year lifespan.

Comment: It seems hopping on three legs is a common quirk in e.g. Jack Russel terriers, even when completely healthy. I don’t have reliable sources to support an answer and of course we are looking at another breed, but when you had him checked by a vet without findings, it may be just a mannerism.

Comment: Is is one step or many? When my dog changes from trot to gallop, he sorts out his hind legs with a (single) hopping step.